# Simple trigger to update two columns in one table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to create a trigger MySQL that updates two fields at the same time.

Whenever a record is added or inserted, I want the contents to be copied to one field or the other, depending on which one is empty/edited.

`due_date` is a `varchar` and `end_date` is a `datetime`.

e.g.

1. IF new record with `due_date` filled in but `end_date` empty → copy `due_date` to `end_date` after insert.
2. IF new record with `end_date` filled in but `due_date` empty → copy `end_date` to `due_date` after insert.
3. IF update to `due_date` → copy that to `end_date` after update
4. IF update to `end_date` → copy that to `due_date` after update

Please note, the `due_date` format is already the correct and same format as datetime.

Comment: it's not that complicated but would like to understand why you want to Update it back.  I mean at first 'due_date = end_date' but then 'end_date =due_date' . Also it would really help if you can share what format the due_date is in '1999-01-31 12.05.000' or '31-JAN-1999'

Comment: Thanks. The format is: `2015-11-16 15:11:50` for both fields. Also the reason is: If on one page users edit the `end_date` then it needs to be copied to the `due_date` and if another user on a different page updates the `due_date` it needs to be copied to the `end_date` that's it!

Comment: You haven't told us what database engine you're using (`sql` is a language which is very, very different from SQL Server the database engine from Microsoft).  Are you using SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Why would `due_date` be a `varchar` rather than a `datetime`?  If your end goal is that both columns have the same data, why do you have two separate columns?  What if an `update` statement changes both columns?  Which value wins?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I use the MySQL database! Also, the reason I need two columns is because the framework I use on one page gives bugs if it's datetime and works perfectly with a varchar, but on another page I use a framework that requires a datetime field! Also, both fields will never be available to the end user at the same time, so this should not form a problem I think.

Comment: Clean up dates _before_ getting to mysql.  Don't have dates as VARCHARs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i have understand what you are saying correctly, following would be the code you may be looking for.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trig_1 before insert
ON  <table_name> FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   IF   new.due_date is not null and new.end_date='' then
        set new.end_date=new.due_date;
   end if;
      IF   new.end_date is not null and new.due_date='' then
        set new.due_date=new.end_date;
   end if;

END;
//


DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trig_2 before update
ON  <table_name> FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

   IF   new.due_date <>old.due_date then
        set new.end_date=new.due_date;
   end if;
      IF   new.end_date <> old.end_date then
        set new.due_date=new.end_date;
   end if;

END;
//
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You probably can't use a simple comparison like `new.due_date <> old.due_date`, because either value (at least the old one) might be null. But as @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ has suggested elsewhere, you could replace it with `NOT (new.due_date <=> old.due_date)`.

Comment: I got some syntax errors like:
`(1064): Syntax error near 'IF new.end_date is not null and new.due_date='' then set new.due_date' at line 1`
and `(1064): Syntax error near 'end if' at line 1`

Comment: @mesqueeb: Maybe you forgot to issue `DELIMITER //` before running the CREATE TRIGGER statement?

Comment: It worked now! Give me a few days to troubleshoot, and I'll come back to this thread. Thank you all so much.